# Rails simple_form, move hint before input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Is there anyway to move the hint component so it appears before the input?

The components currently appear, in the following order: label, input, hint, error.  I've tried adding the :components option but that is not working.

Here's my code:

```
<%= f.input :content, 
            :components => [:label, :hint, :input], 
            :as => :text, 
            hint: 'Please 1) include your exact copy here, 2) upload your copy document in the next step, or 3) describe any content services to include in our estimate.', 
            required: true, 
            :label => "Copy" %>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can modify the Inputs section default wrapper in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`, from:

```
b.use :label_input
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
```

to:

```
b.use :label
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
b.use :input
```

This section starts at line 42 in the default generated simple_form.rb

This will make individual checkboxes look a little odd when they have errors, so you will also want to make a version of the wrapper that is a duplicate of the original config and set it up just for use with the `boolean` input type.  For example:

```
config.wrappers :checks, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.use :placeholder
    b.optional :maxlength
    b.optional :pattern
    b.optional :min_max
    b.optional :readonly

    ## Inputs
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
end
config.wrapper_mappings = { boolean: :checks }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just omit the hint from the `input_field` and use the `hint`helper by itself.  See excerpt from [simple_form docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form):

> Simple Form also allows you to use label, hint, input_field, error and
>   full_error helpers (please take a look at the rdocs for each method
>   for more info):

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.input_field :username %>
  <%= f.hint 'No special characters, please!' %>
  <%= f.error :username, id: 'user_name_error' %>
  <%= f.full_error :token %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That could work but involves fairly extensive refactoring of my code. I was hoping for an easier way to set the order globally.

Comment: You can probably create a custom component and control how the tags are rendered (have not done this before): https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-input-components

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the order of the extensions in the Inputs section of the initializer `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`.

From:

```
## Inputs
b.use :label_input
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
```

To:

```
## Inputs
b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
b.use :label_input
b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
```

I don't know if this is a new feature. Tested with `simple_form` 3.5.0.